# Is it possible to call a variable within an argument from a class?

Tags: python, class, object, printing

I'm trying to return the dictionary `d` that is within the argument `bar` from the class `foo` but the return I get is `<function bar at 0x00000262763B2EE0>`. Is this the best way to do this? I wrote  an example code that I've written to represent what I'm working on which includes a much larger code. It seems to me like I may be going about this wrong, like I shouldn't be calling variables from outside the classes.

```
def bar():
    d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
    return d
class foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self._bar = bar
    def p_dict(self):
        print(self._bar)

test_1 = foo(bar)

test_1.p_dict()
```

Comment: You are not calling `bar` method anywhere.

Comment: print(self._bar())

Comment: You cannot access a local variable from outside the function `bar`. You have to *call* `bar` and save the return value, e.g., `self._bar = bar()`

Comment: try `foo(bar())` and you will access to the value of the function instead of the reference to the function

Comment: to check if it is callable `self._bar() if callable(self._bar) else self._bar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def bar():
    d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
    return d
class foo:
    def __init__(self, _bar):
        self._bar = _bar
    def p_dict(self):
        print(self._bar())

test_1 = foo(bar)

test_1.p_dict()
```